# Using Optimized CSS and JS by Drupal for other files outside Drupal

Tags: javascript, css, drupal, minify

I think my question would be better laid if I write here the scenario of our current set up and the things I want to achieve. We have a Drupal 6 site and freemarker files that are using the same theme as Drupal. Now I have to optimize the loading and reduce the file dependencies of the freemarker files to CSS and JS. I was told to use the minified/optimized JS and CSS of Drupal and delivered it via CDN. But using those minified and CSS alters the design of the freemarker pages. I'm still not sure the solution for this. Thanks for your help in advanced.

Comment: Hi! Andrew. It was actually produced by Drupal when you set the JS and CSS to be minified in Performance settings. Just view source and I can see minified CSS and JS. I wonder if I can just copy it and use it in Freemarker pages.

Answer (score 1):

Validate all of your CSS and look for parsing errors or warnings and correct them. This should prevent layout issues when minifying/optimizing it. I've had this same issues with CSS in the themes of Drupal we created. After fixing parsing errors, I could aggregate just fine.

Comment: Hi! KEvin. Thanks for your response. Do you have any tool that you could recommend for checking errors?

Comment: Thanks again Kevin. I'll take a look and share the results here for the sake of others who might have same questions. =)

Comment: Hi! Kevin. I've already validated the CSS and fixed some parse errors. The thing is, the siFR is not actually working. =(

Comment: So i validated that the problem is the minified JS. =(

Comment: Can you use a packed version instead?

Comment: when you said packed version, what does it mean? Is it the packed jquery? Do you have any other idea on how I can reduce the number of file dependencies in a single page?

Comment: Whenever I have issues with minified js I look for the packed version. Jquery used to have one.

Comment: I see. thanks for that tip Kevin. I decided to use the non-minified js and serve it via cloudfront. Thanks for your time and help.

Comment: anyways, any tool that you can recommend when combining js files?

Answer (score 0):

I may be stating the obvious here, but if you're using the same CSS on two sites and the visual results aren't the same, the markup must be different. So either your markup needs to be changed on one of the sites, or the CSS needs to be made more general to work with both types of markup.

Comment: Hi! Scott. Thanks for sharing your thoughts. In a way, you are really right. However, I'm working on reducing the file dependencies of the freemarker pages. I'll let you know what I found out. Thanks!